# When using a pandas dataframe, how do I add column if does not exist?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to using pandas and am writing a script where I read in a dataframe and then do some computation on some of the columns.

Sometimes I will have the column called "Met":

```py
df = pd.read_csv(File, 
  sep='\t', 
  compression='gzip', 
  header=0, 
  names=["Chrom", "Site", "coverage", "Met"]
)
```

Other times I will have:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(File, 
  sep='\t', 
  compression='gzip', 
  header=0, 
  names=["Chrom", "Site", "coverage", "freqC"]
)
```

I need to do some computation with the "Met" column so if it isn't present I will need to calculate it using:

```py
df['Met'] = df['freqC'] * df['coverage']
```

is there a way to check if the "Met" column is present in the dataframe, and if not add it?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You check it like this:

```
if 'Met' not in df:
    df['Met'] = df['freqC'] * df['coverage']
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449676/14555505 for how to add in multiple columns iff they don't exist

Answer (score 10):

When interested in conditionally adding columns in a [method chain](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining), consider using `pipe()` with a `lambda`:

```py
df.pipe(lambda d: (
    d.assign(Met=d['freqC'] * d['coverage'])
    if 'Met' not in d else d
))
```

Comment: Nice terse solution for chaining

Answer (score 6):

If you were creating the dataframe from scratch, you could create the missing columns without a loop merely by passing the column names into the `pd.DataFrame()` call:

```
cols = ['column 1','column 2','column 3','column 4','column 5']
df = pd.DataFrame(list_or_dict, index=['a',], columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can use [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get.html):

```
df['Met'] = df.get('Met', df['freqC'] * df['coverage'])
```

If the column `Met` exists, the values inside this column are taken. Otherwise `freqC` and `coverage` are multiplied.

Comment: I think this solution is correct but it's not as efficient as the others because the assignation is always done and the product is always done, as well.

Comment: **EDIT**: In fact it may fail always since the DataFrame either has `Met` or `freqC` but not both so in order to be correct you should do something like `df['Met'] = df.get('Met', df.get('freqC') * df['coverage'])` (notice the new get for `freqC`)